# Clock weather widget Honor 5X

Tags: huawei, app-widgets, clock

I have lost my clock/weather widget,, for my Huawei Honor 5X.  Can someone help me get it back?  I am on Android 6.01.  The lack of an app drawer doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can download third party widget from playstore [Weather & Clock Widget Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devexpert.weather&hl=en).